# Distance between headsepline and text in header

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage, footer, cleanthesis

The problem I'm having right now is that I'm not able to close the gap between the text in the header and the headsepline. It only works if I delete the image from the header (see screenshot). How can I bring the text down to the headsepline?

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\RequirePackage{mwe}
\rohead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}

\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}

\KOMAoption{headsepline}{.25pt:\textwidth}

\lohead{\headmark}
\automark{chapter}
```

The next issue that I have is that this code also puts the chapter in the footer and basically deletes the name of the section. But when I delete:     \lohead{\headmark} & \automark{chapter} I'll get a footer, where the current section is marked (see screenshot). And I want to stick with this. So what do I need to do in order to have the chapter name only on the top left corner and the current section on the right side of the footer?

[image]
The code:

```
\automark[section]{chapter}         % automatically marks sections as rightmark
                                    % and chapters as leftmark
\setlength{\footheight}{125pt}      % avoids scrlayer-scrpage warning:
                                    % footheight to low warning
\setlength{\footskip}{185pt}        % BAD HACK that moves the foot downwards
\KOMAoption{footwidth}{foot:53pt}   % BAD HACK that moves the foot towards
                                    % the outer border
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\ctfontfootertext}           % font for footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\ctfontfooterpagenumber}   % font for page numbers



%% Redefinition of the sectionmark (used for footer mark on odd (right) pages)
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{%
        \ctfontfootertext
        \protect\raggedleft%
        {\color{ctcolorfootermark}\textbf{\thesection}}%
        \hspace{.25cm}%
        \protect\begin{minipage}[t]{\minof{\widthof{#1}}{.7\textwidth}}%
            #1%
        \protect\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

%% Vertical line in the footer (between page number and mark)
\newcommand{\ctfooterline}{%
    \color{ctcolorfooterline}\rule[-90pt]{1.25pt}{100pt}%
}

%% Page number for odd (right) pages
\newcommand{\ctfooterrightpagenumber}{%
    \ctfooterline%
    \hspace*{10pt}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
        \pagemark\ %
    \end{minipage}%
}
```

PS: I used the cleanthesis template v.0.4.1 and turned twoside to false!

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, you should really complete your example so that it can directly be compiled. In particular, your code should begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\headmark` by `\leftmark` and use `\cohead`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside=false,headheight=48pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[bibfile=example]{cleanthesis}[2020/06/17]% at least version v.0.4.1

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.25pt:\textwidth}
\cohead{\raisebox{\depth}{\leftmark}\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\cofoot*{}% remove the second page number in footer on pages using style plain:

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\chapter{Long long long long long long long long long long long long chapter title}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Additional remark:** The redefinition of `\chaptermark` in package `cleanthesis` leads to incorrect header/footer entries if you use `\addchap` for unnumbered chapters. The same for `\sectionmark`. Additionally the font of the header entries on the second and following pages of ToC, LoF, LoT etc. will differ from the other pages in the document.

Note, that the suggestion above only works, if the image is smaller than `\headwidth`-`0.65\textwidth`-`.25cm`-width of the chapter prefix and chapter number. The redefinition of `\chaptermark` in package `cleanthesis` reserves a fixed vertical space of `0.65\textwidth` for the chapter title (without chapter prefix and number and space between number and title).

If your image is wider, you can redefine `\chapterformat` and `\chaptermarkformat` and change the content of `\cohead`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside=false,headheight=48pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[bibfile=example]{cleanthesis}[2020/06/17]% at least version v.0.4.1

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.25pt:\textwidth}
\cohead{\parbox[b]{\linewidth-5cm}{\leftmark}\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=4.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\cofoot*{}% remove the second page number in footer on pages using style plain
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\@hangfrom{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{\MakeMarkcase{#1}}}{}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\bfseries\color{ctcolorfootermark}\MakeMarkcase{\chapapp\ \thechapter}\hspace{.25cm}}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\ctfontfootertext}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\normalcolor}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\chapter{Long long long long long long long long long long long long chapter title}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me already so much. But I've got just one more question, when you change the image to a wider one: \includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}}. It will force the image to be in the center of the header. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I have changed my answer: option `autooneside=false` is not needed, because `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` are redefined *after* `\automark`. Note, that `\automark` would reset `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` to the original KOMA-Script definition.